# Sound disappear from time to time when plugging/unplugging 3.5 jack headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, xps

On my Ubuntu 16.04 the sound can disappear from time to time when plugging/unplugging headphones.
I tried reloading alsa but it doesn't work consistently, or rather only works very rarely.
alsamixer seems to be fine. Full reboot usually helps, but it is ridiculous. I never got my bluetooth headphones to work properly on ubuntu, now it turns out even oldschool 3.5 jack is buggy.

Laptop: Dell XPS 9550

**UPDATE:**
I also noticed it never happens after a complete reboot. So there must be a way to reload everything sound-related so that I don't have to reload the whole system.
One other thing, when this problem occurs, I usually hear a very annoying white noise for just a moment on inserting a jack.

Comment: look at `alsamixer`if there is `<Auto-Mute>` feature and if it's enabled. In some cases, turning this feature off solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me as well, and the only solution I ever found was to brute force it with a bash script which I can conveniently execute with the command `fixaudio`. It does slightly more than just reloading `alsa`, but also restarts `pulseaudio`. It's not an ideal solution, I admit, but it works. I'm on 16.04 as well, with an XPS13.

```
#!/bin/bash
pulseaudio --kill
sudo alsa force-reload
pulseaudio --start
```

If this does work, you can save it as a file with no extension, make it executable, and place it in `/bin/` to run whenever for a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks, @jphollowed. I will try when it happens again and let you know.

Comment: what do you do with the jack? Do you unplug it before this procedure and plug it back in afterwards?

Comment: @yuranos87 I just run this when my sound isn't working (no sounds no matter what my volume settings are), whether headphones are plugged in or not.

Comment: I have tried your method and even though it didn't work right away, the headset started to function after I re-plugged it. If I will able to reproduce it consistently, will be happy to accept your answer. Thanks again!